# How to [create matrix (M x d) using vectors (d, 1) as its rows (1, d)? / assign vec' (i.e. vec transpose) to rows of matrix?]

Tags: matlab, vector, matrix

I'm trying to take `M` images (say `I`) of `d` pixels each; convert them into a vector `ImgVctr`; and store them as arrays of an `M x d` matrix. How do i do it?

I tried the following

```
ImgVctr = I(:);
img_vctr_arr(i,:) = ImgVctr';
```

but it fails with the error :

```
Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.
```

Any suggestions for a simple way to do this ?

All help will be appreciated !

Edit:
complete matlab code attached below:

```
img_vctr_arr = zeros (3, 38*28);
for i = 1:3
    clearvars I;
    fname = sprintf('a%d.png', i);    
    I = imread(fname);
    I = rgb2gray (I);

    ImgVctr = I(:);
    img_vctr_arr(i,:) = ImgVctr';
    figure (), imshow (I);

    [x, y] = size(I);
    fprintf ('%d, ', x);
    fprintf ('%d\n', y);
end;
```

~ Thankyou

Comment: What is the size of `I`? Is it 3D with all the images or is that a single instance of an image?

Comment: say 38 x 28. I have converted it into a vector of size 1064 (=38*28).
and its a single image .. I have 3 such images, to make a matrix of size [3, 1064]

Comment: Where are all the images stored then?  What variable(s) contain all the data?

Comment: yes, it was my mistake 
@chappjc, appreciate your tips
ty

Comment: I was using 38*28 .. whereas my image was 38*26

Comment: PS: its amazing to see how one can always shorten one's code to achieve a work in matlab!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pre-allocate the matrix like:

```
img_vctr_arr = zeros(M,d);
```

Then fill it:

```
img_vctr_arr(i,:) = I(:)'; % do not even need the '
```

**Just ensure that `numel(I)` equals `d`.**